# Jquery Datatable not working when call through Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using JQuery Datatable for display table values, I am fetching values from Ajax, but normal table is displaying,JQuery Datatable is not supporting. If without Ajax JQuery Datatable is works fine, Please help me where I am doing wrong.

```
   <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    showModal();
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "searching": false
    } );
} );
function showModal(){
$.ajax({
    url : "<c:url value='/EndToEndServlet' />",
    data : {
    },
    type : "GET",
    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("ENTER INTO JSON");
    var table =' <table id="example" class="table table-striped " width="100%"> <thead>';
        table +=' <tr class="success">';
        table +='<th>Sender</th>';
        table +='<th>Recipient</th>';
        table +='<th>Mail Server</th>';
        table +='<th>Arrival Time</th>';
        table +='</tr>';
        table +='</thead>';
    for(var i=0;i<data.u.length;i++)
    {
    table += '<tbody><tr><td>'+data.u[i].sender+'</td><td>'+data.u[i].receiver+'</td><td>'+
    data.u[i].mail_server+'</td><td>'
    +data.u[i].arrival_time+'</td></tr>';
    }
    table += '<tbody>';
        table +='</table>';
        $("#resp1").html(table);                                    
    }
});
}
</script>
</div>
<div id="resp1"></div>
```

Comment: ajax is **asynchronous**. You are initializing the plugin before the table exists

Comment: I am the beginner of this Jquery, I did not understand your solution properly, Can you modify in my code where I did mistake.

Comment: Initialize plugin in `success` callback after you insert the new table html

Comment: success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {$('#example').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "searching": false
    } );} sorry for disturbing you,like this after success should I need to add pluggin.

Comment: Yes ...right after `$("#resp1").html(table);` ... that is what is inserting the table

Comment: $("#resp1").html(table); this is for display table in html

Comment: success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  console.log("ENTER INTO JSON");
   $('#example').DataTable( {
          "pagingType": "full_numbers",
          "searching": false
      } ); I tryed this but getting TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you construct your datatable your

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    showModal();
});

function showModal(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<c:url value='/EndToEndServlet' />",
        data: {
        },
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("ENTER INTO JSON");
            var table = ' <table id="example" class="table table-striped " width="100%"> <thead>';
            table += ' <tr class="success">';
            table += '<th>Sender</th>';
            table += '<th>Recipient</th>';
            table += '<th>Mail Server</th>';
            table += '<th>Arrival Time</th>';
            table += '</tr>';
            table += '</thead>';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.u.length; i++) {
                table += '<tbody><tr><td>' + data.u[i].sender + '</td><td>' + data.u[i].receiver + '</td><td>' +
                    data.u[i].mail_server + '</td><td>'
                    + data.u[i].arrival_time + '</td></tr>';
            }
            table += '<tbody>';
            table += '</table>';
            $("#resp1").html(table);

            $('#example').DataTable({
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "searching": false
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this but getting error at closing of showmodel() function before $('#example').DataTable( {
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "searching": false
        } );

Comment: I only edited position of $('#example').DataTable(... if you have any other errors i cant test it cause of your url is not working with me. But in first look you are creating more than one <tbody> tag in for loop.

Comment: Thanks its working fine. table += '<tr><td><a href="javascript:show('+data.u[i].sender+')">'+data.u[i].sender+'</a></td><td>'+data.u[i].receiver+'</td><td>. getting error while calling show method inside table, if take string, can you please find the mistake.

Comment: Try <a onClick="show(data)")></a> instead of <a href="javascript:show('+data.u[i].sender+')">